# How to understand "we take a bite out of one of those damn russians"?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, offensive-language

I can't understand the sentence **we take a bite out of one of those damn russians**

I think it means that the Japanese are ready to attack and drive out the Russians.

Others believe that the Japanese have problems and the Russians can win this battle.
[image: manga source]

Comment: Is this a joke about cannibalism?

Comment: Note that the word in the comic strip is "bite" , not "bit"

Comment: oh, yes, I see mistake, thanks to you for noticing.

Comment: They seem to be starving and you can clearly see a frame where someone takes a bite out of a finger and the spits it out. That's what 'chomp' means (take a bite).

Comment: hmm, I didn't think about the connection with the previous frame. It's a really interesting idea